# PHP - When answering an incoming sms in twilio how to store the source number in a file?

Tags: php, twilio

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL );
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
$number = $_POST['From'];
$body = $_POST['Body'];

header('Content-Type: text/xml');
```

this part of the code does not work

```
$fp = fopen($number .'.txt', 'w');
fwrite($fp, $number);
fclose($fp);

?>

<Response>
    <Message>
        Hello <?php echo $number ?>.
        You said <?php echo $body ?>
    </Message>
</Response>
```

How do I have PHP save the phone number in a local file, when the received SMS response is sent?

Comment: What's the error message that you're receiving?

Comment: twilio sends warning 12200, Schema validation warning and does not send the sms reply message

Comment: You excuse my ignorance, it was only the permissions in the folder where you needed to create the file, I gave you write access and the file was created correctly.